# XML and PHP5 DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom

I am developing an application were I need to transform XML documents that look like this(words.xml):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<!DOCTYPE words SYSTEM "words.dtd">
<words>
<word id="word_1">Alfa</word>
<word id="word_2">Beta</word>
<word id="word_3">Gamma</word>
<word id="word_4">Delta</word>
<word id="word_5">Zeta</word>
</words>
```

Using PHP5 and DOM. I would like the result to be (in this case):

```
word_1 = Alfa
word_2 = Beta
word_3 = Gamma
word_4 = Delta
word_5 = Zeta
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php

$xmlHitzakDok = new DOMDocument();
$xmlHitzakDok->load("words.xml");

$x = $xmlHitzakDok->documentElement;
foreach ($x->childNodes AS $item)
  {
  print $item->nodeName . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br />";
  }
?>
```

I am getting no results. Which is the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't it be something more along the lines of "node->attribute( 'id' )" = ?

Comment: error reporting and display errors set properly? no error found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not that `$xmlHitzakDok->documentElement` is not the `<words>` element, it's the document itself, it does not contain any data.

I suggest using xpath to get the elements you want.

```
$xPath = new DOMXPath($xmlHitzakDok);

foreach ($xPath->query('//words/word') AS $item)
{
    echo $item->getAttribute('id') . " = " . $item->nodeValue . "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: Works for me (http://codepad.org/oi3XP7cm).  Are you sure that `words.xml` exists?  Try using `$xmlHitzakDok->load(realpath("words.xml"));`.

Comment: Or try doing `if($xmlHitzakDok->load("words.xml") === FALSE){die('error loading file');}`  My guess is the file isn't being loaded correctly.

Comment: Hi, I did that and "error loading file" message appeared on the browser. I dont know why the file cant be loaded. "words.xml" is located on the same folder as the php, exactly in /var/www/myfolder/. Why is this? Any idea @Rocket? Thanks.

Comment: I finally solved the problem, had to change privileges to words.xml. Thanks for your time @Rocket.

Comment: @Rocket: `$xmlHitzakDok->documentElement` is the `<words>` element, you can check that with `->documentElement->tagName` easily, see as well http://codepad.org/YdCCk4LX (just FYI)

Comment: @hakre: Heh, you're right.  Though `$xmlHitzakDok->documentElement->childNodes` still doesn't work =/

Comment: @Rocket: http://codepad.org/J8qIRJzO - looks okay to me. Probably just the I/O error reading the file for TS.

Comment: @hakre: Why doesn't this work?  http://codepad.org/xu5hyRhU  EDIT: It seems `getAttribute` isn't working because it's a text node.

Comment: @hakre: I figured it out!  `childNodes` is getting ALL children.  That means it's getting the `<word>` element, and its child, which is a text node.  http://codepad.org/wuESlNw1

Comment: @hakre: Anyway, that's why I like my xpath solution :-P